# conda package on Nexus Repository

Tags: python, pip, conda, nexus, pypi

My company uses Nexus repository as npm proxy for package management. Does anyone have experience using Nexus to hold Conda packages (Python) and for proxy?

In the Nexus documentation, it clearly says that the Nexus supports the PyPI repository, but does it also support Conda repositories?

Answer (score 3):

We do not support Conda packages at current time. I myself have never tried it, and I suspect it would not work to try using a PyPi hosted repo, etc... for Conda packages.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the fast response. I'm relativity new to Nexus Repository. Do you believe that I can support Conda in Nexus using "nexus raw repository", or I'm waisting my time. I appreciate your help and advise very much. Thanks Saar

Comment: I don't imagine that would work, raw is VERY simple (and for a reason, it's mainly for curl/wget of files in and out). Conda I imagine has specific endpoints it needs to use, and likely other fun things. If you have interest in writing a Conda plugin for Nexus Repository 3, I can get you some help there :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. your offer to help me write conda plugin for Nexus is very tempting, there is a small chance that I would find the time to do it, I guess it is not easy task. if you have some instruction documentation how to do it, I would like if you can share it with me. but please don't waste time at the moment, because the chance for me to find time for this is very low. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: This isn't currently working to my knowledge, but here is someone who wrote an apt-get plugin: https://github.com/mpoindexter/nexus-repository-apt

Comment: Hi Again, I managed to use conda with Nexus, using "raw hosted" repository. the trick was to create inside the repository two folders, the "win-64" folder which I uploaded there (using curl) the packages I want, I also needed to create a folder called "noarch" which is require by conda (put inside some files). I want to configure also a "raw proxy" repository for Conda, for this I need to create in the proxy repository a folder called "noarch" and upload the same files, when trying do do it  I get "Put" error. is it possible to manually load artifacts to a proxy repository?????  Thanks Saar

Comment: No, proxies do not work that way as they are supposed to be just a representation of a remote. That is why we created hosted repositories. Get in touch and maybe we can work on a true Conda implementation :)

Comment: So, did @user1470957 and DarthHater get in touch to create a true Conda implementation?

Comment: Nothing yet! More than game to help out if someone wants to work with me!

Comment: Late add, someone created a ticket, you can follow along for formal update: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-16932.  It links here which is how I found this post.

Comment: We are still working on this, but there's a POC/prototype of Conda proxy here: https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-conda

Comment: Any update on this?