# is there a way to host conda packages on a private nexus repository

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, nexus

I would like to use the company Nexus repository to upload python packages and enable other people within the company to download them via conda. Nexus definitely seems to support pip, but not sure how about conda.

This question is quite similar and says conda not supported, but it is also quite old
[conda package on Nexus Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42346047/conda-package-on-nexus-repository)

Is there currently a way to have conda packages on Nexus repo and download them via conda?

Comment: Would be better to get an updated answer on the older question since it is essentially identical. I'm closing this a duplicate and adding a bounty on the other one to draw attention.